# Wireframe of top and bottom caps on cylinder

Tags: wireframe

I have a vertical cylinder and I want a wireframe on just the horizontal circular outlines around the top and bottom caps. However, when I apply the wireframe modifier, it wireframes not just these, but also each of the vertical edges around the outside that make up the faces of the circular shape around. Is there an easy way of getting just top and bottom?

Comment: Have you tried using Mesh wireframe? In Edit mode, select the edge loops on both ends of the cylinder and find 'Wire Frame' in the search menu(spacebar).

Comment: would you like a wireframe mesh or render?             you can split into two separate objects, and apply them wireframe modifier to only the mesh you like,

or using freestyle you can render wireframe on selected edges.

Comment: @asoftbird solution worked. Can't seem to accept your answer though.

Comment: @Stevod I considered my suggestion more of a question than an answer, will answer it now so you can mark it complete :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: I already posted this answer as a comment; posting it as answer now so the question can be completed. Also added some extra information + images for clarity.*

Have you tried using Mesh wireframe? In Edit mode, select the edge loops on both ends of the cylinder and find 'Wire Frame' in the search menu(spacebar). Uncheck 'Replace' if you also want to keep the cylinder shape.

Note that this is destructive modification; using the Wireframe modifier would likely be more convenient, but I think that's not applicable since if you use the modifier, the edge vertices are shared with the top/bottom face vertices, so they will likely always be modified together. The modifier also doesn't seem to work on only selected vertices / vertex group.

[image]